# Get last row and last column or UsedRange from a closed file (and keep it closed - ADO)

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ado

I need to copy the UsedRange from seven closed files to a new workbook. Each source file is around 200M, thus I want to extract the information without open them.

I've read some good information from this site https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win024.htmthis, but the functions here require as a parameter the specific range to be extracted. unfortunatelly this ranges change so I'd love to find a way to know how to get the last column and last row.

Thanks in advance,

Mike

Answer (score 3):

> Get last row and last column or UsedRange from a closed file (and keep it closed - ADO)...
> I'd love to find a way to know how to get the last column and last row.

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Private Const adOpenKeyset As Integer = 1
Private Const adCmdText As Integer = 1

Sub Sample()
    Dim MyExcelFile As String
    Dim MyConnectionString As String
    Dim SQLString As String
    Dim MyCon As Object, MyRecordset As Object
    Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Long
    
    '~~> Change this to the relevant excel file
    MyExcelFile = "C:\Users\routs\Desktop\Test.xlsx"
    
    '~~> Connection string
    MyConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & _
                         MyExcelFile & _
                        ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";"
                        
    Set MyCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    MyCon.Open ConnectionString:=MyConnectionString
    
    '~~> Getting details from Sheet1. Change as applicable
    SQLString = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]"
    
    Set MyRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
    MyRecordset.Open Source:=SQLString, _
                     ActiveConnection:=MyCon, _
                     CursorType:=adOpenKeyset, _
                     Options:=adCmdText
                     
    MyRecordset.MoveLast
    
    '~~> Last Row
    lRow = MyRecordset.RecordCount + 1
    '~~> Last Column
    lCol = MyRecordset.Fields.Count
    
    MsgBox "Last Row:=" & lRow & vbNewLine & _
           "Last Column:=" & lCol
    
    MyRecordset.Close
    MyCon.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: That's was exactly what I was looking for!! thanks!! Any bibliography about how to use the ADODB.RecordSet object?

Comment: I had a good set of codes on my website but it got hacked. I am in the process of rebuilding it. In the meantime you can always google VBA CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")